# How can I check if a given image is CMYK in java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

For my project I need to detect if an image is CMYK. Is there any class in jai or is there any other library which might be helpfull?

I try to read a CMYK file and disply it but the color got messed up.

```
RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("stream", stream);
ScrollingImagePanel panel = new ScrollingImagePanel(image1, image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
JFrame window = new JFrame("JAI Sample Program");
window.add(panel);
window.pack();
window.show();
```

And it consider the image rgb if I try to detect CMYK by the following code:

```
if (image1.getColorModel().getColorSpace().getType()==ColorSpace.TYPE_CMYK) {
        System.out.println("CMYK");
} 
if (image1.getColorModel().getColorSpace().getType()==ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB) {
    System.out.println("RGB");
}
```

Comment: Why does the code in the second sample not solve your problem?

Comment: cause with a very quick testing I did, it recognizes the image as of RGB type, even if it's of CMYK type. Can someone provide a real CMYK type image to test with ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, you use wrong classes. These are others that support CMYK images:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html

Comment: @Jiří Ahoj. Updated.