# Getting ColorMode from a ImageView Bitmap

Tags: android, android-imageview

Looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326660/how-can-i-check-if-a-given-image-is-cmyk-in-java), Im trying to determine of the image in view is of CMYK colormode or not. If it it, I it must not try to display it, and continue with the next image in my list

This is how I am setting up my ImageView

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, imageWidth, imageWidth);
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap image = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path, 1280, 700);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

How do I determine if this image is CMYK ? Or simply said, I do I determine if this image can be displayed or not